# Is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS usable with the AMD Ryzen 5 5600G CPU and, if not, which Ubuntu and/or kernel version do I need?

Tags: 18.04, kernel, amd-ryzen

I would like to buy an AMD Ryzen 5 5600G and my question would be, is this going to work under Ubuntu 18.04 or do I have to do something to make it work (and approximately what)?
I would like to keep my current installation and SSD. I would like it to be completely stable. Graphics performance is secondary but I would like it to be at least "80%" good and no bugs about flickering and such (I would like to use the iGPU).

My current kernel version: Linux 4.15.0-193-generic x86_64
Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Desktop environment: LXDE (Openbox 3.6.1)

I would like to keep my current distro version because I use a specific version of Audacity in my workflow but I can upgrade my kernel or even the distro if I must.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: We don't provide hardware recommendations here as a rule. It's not good practice to transplant an operating system to entirely different hardware and it doesn't make sense to hold on to 18.04 when it's going to become unsupported in a few months. Word of advice: figure out how to adapt or configure your workflow on supported software instead of trying to cling to versions that will eventually become unsupported and increasingly difficult to maintain

Comment: Since 18.04 has only about 1 year left before it goes EOL you may want to consider upgrading the system before installing the new video card. Yes with the correct driver it should be fine.

Comment: Please refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll note "*Shopping or Hardware Recommendations*" are off-topic.  Ubuntu Forums allows those sort of *opinion* based questions.

Comment: @Nmath I understand; I didn't mean it that way, I am sure I want that CPU and iGPU but am not sure that Ubuntu version will work with that. I have slightly reworded the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Short Version

No. Your kernel version is too old and it doesn't support your iGPU.

Install a newer version like 20.04 LTS

## Longer version

If you really want to use 18.04 LTS, you'll have to install the [HWE stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) and possibly you might have to install a newer kernel by yourself (either download a mainline deb or build it yourself from source). However IIRC the HWE kernel should support your iGPU.

After that, I think your iGPU should be supported by Mesa, but if not, then you'll have to use a Mesa PPA like [Kisak's](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekisak/+archive/ubuntu/turtle).

Honestly you should upgrade to 20.04.5 LTS which is known to fully work on your HW configuration.

If screwing up the upgrade is what worries you, and you have a big external HDD, boot up from a live USB, download the entirety of /dev/sda ([via dd + lz4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/593776/dd-lz4-compression-and-de-compression)) in case you screw up and decide to revert the upgrade.