# Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS - AMD Ryzen 7 5700U with Radeon Graphics - Video/graphics driver

Tags: 18.04, video

I am trying to make the graphical driver to work in the setup below, but without success.

```
Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
AMD Ryzen 7 5700U with Radeon Graphics
HP 255 G8 Notebook
```

I know the Ubuntu version is very old, but it is a constraint for me.

Please, someone could help me?

I have the Ubuntu version (18.04...) updated (it has the open source AMD drivers distributed by Ubuntu) and I also tried to update from other repository (https://ubunlog.com/en/how-to-install-amd-ati-drivers-in-ubuntu-18-04/). AMD seems doesn't has available the Linux driver for this processor (https://www.amd.com/en/support/cpu/amd-ryzen-processors/amd-ryzen-7-desktop-processors/amd-ryzen-7-5700x).

```
lspci | grep -e VGA

04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Lucienne (rev c1)
```

Comment: Don't forget Ubuntu 18.04 LTS was released in 2018-April (why it's 18.04 with the *year.month* format used) which had 5 years of *standard* supported life..  Run `ubuntu-support-status` to confirm your status, and you'll note EOSS has occurred. Some architectures will continue to get upgrades during May 2023 due to a Canonical decision to extend life (*by one month*), but your system is effectively EOSS now & you should plan your upgraded asap.  EOSS for all 18.04 is 31-May-2023.

Comment: I don't see any solution for a 1 year old upper level cpu working with an OS that is out of development. So here is a possible solution. Get an external GPU adapter and depending on what level of gaming you're interested in doing, purchase a GPU. Something like RX480 or RX580. Even older R9 are decent option. Is that what you're looking for? Some gaming power?

Comment: Thank you for the help. It seems there is no an easy solution, unless to update the Ubuntu version. My use is not for gaming, but for academic purpose. Thank you again.

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/05/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-begins-31-may-2023/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 18.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com//blog/18-04-end-of-standard-support

Answer (score 0):

I expected the same problem at Ubuntu 18.04 with AMD Ryzen 2/3. I think the only solution is to upgrade at least to Ubuntu 18.10 as it was the first version which supports these GPU. Ubuntu 20.04 and newer support them well.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10 is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus off-topic on this site (refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic). Your tested & supported *release-upgrade* path is now also gone, as 18.10 upgraded to 19 04 which now too is EOL. Refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades  http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/07/19/ubuntu-18-10-cosmic-cuttlefish-end-of-life-reached-on-july-18-2019/

Comment: Thank you for the help. It seems there is no an easy solution, unless to update the Ubuntu version. Thank you again.

Comment: Maybe some manual manipulations will be helpful which are described here - https://askubuntu.com/a/1433555/917609